# Отцентровать изображение

Tags: html, css

Как можно отцентровать изображение чтоб оно постоянно не прыгало то вверх то вниз ?

**html файл**

```
  <h2>ЦГОК.РОФ.Фильтрация</h2>  
    <div id="w-panel" >
        <object id="map-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/FILTRATION_MAIN_1.svg"  height="860px"></object>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
body, html {
          max-width: 100%;
          max-height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: helvetica;   
          color: #000000;
          background: black;
}
#map-svg{


    display:block; 
    margin:50px auto 20px;
}
header{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для отцентровки чего либо в css лучше использовать flexbox. На примере снизу вывел блок который по отношению к его родителю всегда будет по центру.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.children{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Сделал так же но блок ушел вверх